# "Не" слитно или раздельно

Tags: частица-не

Ты должен не трясущейся рукой, без жадности взять и ...

Поэтому оставим суждения о его испорченности или не испорченности на Суд Божий.

У каждого из нас накопилось очень много не вовремя прочтенных молитв,...

Как в этих предложениях пишется "не", слитно или раздельно, и почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

!) **Ты должен не (трясущейся рукой), без жадности взять и ...** НЕ относится к словосочетанию.

2) **Поэтому оставим суждения о его испорченности или неиспорченности на Суд Божий.** НЕ ― приставка, нет отрицания, утвердительный смысл.

3) **У каждого из нас накопилось очень много не вовремя прочтенных молитв...**. НЕ относится к наречию ***вовремя***, только отрицательное значение, не может быть приставкой.

Answer (score 1):

**Нетрясущаяся (твердая) рука**. Следуйте правилам написания не- с прилагательными. Прилагательное с не- может быть заменено синонимом без не-. Нет отрицания, нет противопоставления.

**Неиспорченность**. Следуйте правилам написания не- с существительными. Частица не- и существительное образуют новое, противоположное по значению слово. Нет отрицания, нет противопоставления.

**Не вовремя** пишется раздельно. См. ответ Грамоты:

> Вопрос № 286450
>   Почему "невовремя" пишется раздельно, если в качестве наречия оно относится к "отыменным", и должно писаться слитно? И не является сказуемым, при этом.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Отрицание не пишется раздельно с наречиями (кроме образованных от имен прилагательных с помощью суффикса -о), а также с неизменяемыми словами, употребляющимися в роли сказуемого, например: не вблизи, **не вовремя**, не вполне, не вправе, не впрок, не всерьёз, не вскользь, не вчера, не досыта, не завтра, не зря, не иначе, не навек, не навсегда, не нарочно, не очень, не позади, не полностью, не сегодня, не слишком, не сверху, не сразу; не жаль, не замужем, не зазорно, не надо. См.: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2006. § 146.

Comment: Напрасно Вы меня правите. Ну при чем там твердая рука? Смысл здесь такой: скупой человек даже если что-то отдает людям, то отдает трясущимися от жадности руками.  Однородные члены, отрицание выражено частицей НЕ и предлогом БЕЗ. А вот и источник, по которому можете свериться: Будда ответил: "А теперь правой рукой, которая как бы ты сам, отдавай золото, шелка и дорогие одежды левой руке, которую представь себе твоим просителем. Но старайся отдавать не трясущимися руками, без жадности".http://spiritual.ru/lib/otvaga5.html

Comment: @Jasmin Согласен, согласен! Не вник в смысл. Но пусть наш диалог остается для других читателей и поможет им понять разницу.